# Summarizing a data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to take the following data, and then uses this data to create a table which has the information broken down by state.

Here's the data:

```
> head(mydf2, 10)
    lead_id buyer_account_id amount state
1  52055267               62    300    CA
2  52055267               64    264    CA
3  52055305               64    152    CA
4  52057682               62     75    NJ
5  52060519               62    750    OR
6  52060519               64    574    OR
15 52065951               64    152    TN
17 52066749               62    600    CO
18 52062751               64    167    OR
20 52071186               64    925    MN
```

I've allready subset the states that I'm interested in and have just the data I'm interested in:

```
mydf2 = subset(mydf, state %in% c("NV","AL","OR","CO","TN","SC","MN","NJ","KY","CA"))
```

Here's an idea of what I'm looking for:

```
State     Amount       Count
NV        1              50  
NV        2              35  
NV        3              20
NV        4              15
AL        1              10 
AL        2              6
AL        3              4
AL        4              1
...
```

For each state, I'm trying to find a count for each amount "level." I don't necessary need to group the amount variable, but keep in mind that they are are not just 1,2,3, etc

```
> mydf$amount
   [1]  300  264  152   75  750  574  113  152  750  152  675  489  188  263  152  152  600  167   34  925  375  156  675  152  488  204  152  152
  [29]  600  489  488   75  152  152  489  222  563  215  452  152  152   75  100  113  152  150  152  150  152  452  150  152  152  225  600  620
  [57]  113  152  150  152  152  152  152  152  152  152  640  236  152  480  152  152  200  152  560  152  240  222  152  152  120  257  152  400
```

Is there an elegant solution for this in R for this or will I be stuck using Excel (yuck!).

Comment: Have you looked at `?table` yet?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "I don't necessary need to group the amount variable, but keep in mind that they are are not just 1,2,3, etc".

Comment: For the example, I used 1,2,3,etc, but there are actually lots of amount values. That's what I meant.

Comment: You realize though, that if you don't group the amount variable, you're likely to get a *very* long `data.frame` as the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand correctly (you have two `data.frames` `mydf` and `mydf2`). I'll assume your data is in `mydf`. Using `aggregate`:

```
mydf$count <- 1:nrow(mydf)
aggregate(data = mydf, count ~ amount + state, length)
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Note: here `count` is a variable that is created just to get directly the output of the 3rd column as `count`.

Alternatives with `ddply` from `plyr`:

```
# no need to create a variable called count
ddply(mydf, .(state, amount), summarise, count=length(lead_id))
```

Here' one could use any column that exists in one's data instead of `lead_id`. Even `state`:

```
ddply(mydf, .(state, amount), summarise, count=length(state))
```

Or equivalently without using summarise:

```
ddply(mydf, .(state, amount), function(x) c(count=nrow(x)))
```

Comment: I get `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'lead_id' not found` if "lead_id" is not quoted. Can you try it with my toy example and see if it works as expected for you? Also with the same toy example, `aggregate` clocks in at >25 times faster than `ddply`. It's also possible to directly include count in `aggregate` (`aggregate(data = mydf, 1:nrow(mydf) ~ amount + state, length)`) but you'll have to clean up the resulting variable names.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, because `length("lead_id") = 1`. It is just a character vector. You might have gotten the whole count column as 1.

Comment: @Arun, well that was dumb of me. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Here's my understanding of what you're trying to do:

Start with a simple `data.frame` with 26 states and amounts only ranging from 1 to 50 (which is much more restrictive than what you have in your example, where the range is much higher).

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(
  state = sample(letters, 500, replace = TRUE),
  amount = sample(1:50, 500, replace = TRUE)
)

head(mydf)
#   state amount
# 1     g     28
# 2     j     35
# 3     o     33
# 4     x     34
# 5     f     24
# 6     x     49
```

Here's some straightforward tabulation. I've also removed any instances where frequency equals zero, and I've reordered the output by state.

```
temp1 <- data.frame(table(mydf$state, mydf$amount))
temp1 <- temp1[!temp1$Freq == 0, ]
head(temp1[order(temp1$Var1), ])
#      Var1 Var2 Freq
# 79      a    4    1
# 157     a    7    2
# 391     a   16    1
# 417     a   17    1
# 521     a   21    1
# 1041    a   41    1
dim(temp1) # How many rows/cols
# [1] 410   3
```

Here's a little bit different tabulation. We are tabulating *after* grouping the "amount" values. Here, I've manually specified the breaks, but you could just as easily let R decide what it thinks is best.

```
temp2 <- data.frame(table(mydf$state, 
                          cut(mydf$amount, 
                              breaks = c(0, 12.5, 25, 37.5, 50), 
                              include.lowest = TRUE)))
temp2 <- temp2[!temp2$Freq == 0, ]
head(temp2[order(temp2$Var1), ])
#    Var1      Var2 Freq
# 1     a  [0,12.5]    3
# 27    a (12.5,25]    3
# 79    a (37.5,50]    3
# 2     b  [0,12.5]    2
# 28    b (12.5,25]    6
# 54    b (25,37.5]    5
dim(temp2)
# [1] 103   3
```